# Getting PDF size in millimeters with image-magick on Linux

Tags: linux, image, pdf, imagemagick

Is there some image-magick tool to get the size of a PDF file in millimeters?
I've tried with the imagemagick "identify" tool but the informations are only in pixels. How can I specify to output the information in millimeters together with the DPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the first dozen lines of `identify -verbose`. It should list the following info.

- Geometry
- Resolution
- Print size
- Units

The `Print size` can be converted to mm easily, or found via google quickly.

For example...

```
identify -verbose document.pdf | head -12
```

Which returns

```
Image: /full/path/to/document.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 792x612+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 11x8.5
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16/8-bit
```

So about 25.4 mm per inch will result in

```
11 * 25.4 = 279.4mm
8.5 * 25.4 = 215.9mm
```

Of course YMMV if the PDF is a non-traditional page-size.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for :) Now I'm sure my poster is fitting A0 size.

Comment: It's actually not "about 25.4 mm per inch". For more than half a century, the inch has been *defined* as *exactly* 25.4 mm. (Sorry, I couldn't resist pointing this out. Some people might find this information useful.)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size in pixel you then need to decide if they are pixels/inch or pixels/mm and you can then do a calculation.